# Koa Error Handling: is `return` necessary?

Tags: error-handling, koa

I'm using koa-routers to handle a route for making a send email request to a third-party api. Am I error handling correctly? Do I need to return anything? Should I return `ctx.response`? I see some examples that ends the func with await next(). However, I'm assuming I don't need this as there is no other func/middleware to downstream to.

```
router.post('sendemail', async (ctx) => {
  const emailData = ctx.request.body;
  try {
    await someEmailApi({
      recipient: {
        name: emailData.recipientName,
        address: emailData.recipientEmail,
      },
      sender: {
        name: emailData.senderName,
        address: emailData.senderEmail,
      },
      subject: mail.subject,
      message: mail.message,
    });

    ctx.response.status = 200;
    ctx.response.body = 'OK';
  } catch (err) {

    ctx.response.status = err.status;
    ctx.response.body = err.message';
    ctx.throw(ctx.response.status, ctx.response.body);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So because this is a route handler, you usually don't call `await next()` because the route handler is the "inner-most" middleware anyway, so `next()` is a no-op.

If you are using `ctx.throw` you don't need to set the status and body separately.

This should be enough:

```
ctx.throw(err.status, err.message)
```